# SimpleXML and insert data into MySQL using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, curl, simplexml

I have used SimpleXML to get XML data from a source that required authenticiation. Using cURL I have been able to get back a result. However when I have tried to get the data into a MySQL database nothing is inserted.

Now I think it's because I have not done something to the XML data. However I am a newbie to XML data and have always worked with database stuff so could do with some help.

I have had a look around and I'm probably duplicating another question on here, but my confusion is over what I am looking at. If I can figure out the "why", I'll get to the "how"!.

Here is the output I get:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [bookingDataResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [bookingDataResult] => <Bookings><SupplierCode>ABCD</SupplierCode><ServiceName>Service 1</ServiceName><UnitCode>ABC123</UnitCode></Bookings><Bookings><SupplierCode>XYZ</SupplierCode><ServiceName>Service 2</ServiceName><UnitCode>XYZ123</UnitCode></Bookings>
        )

)
```

I presume that I need to transform the result of the above and then get that data to insert into the database. However this is where I am stuck.

I'll use PDO and a foreach to get the data into the database, but any help on getting to that point would be very useful guys.

Cheers

UPDATE @ 11:18GMT:
This update covers the database insert I have coded:

```
$servername = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDatabase";

$db_cstr = "mysql:host=" . $servername . "; dbname=" . $dbname;

$conn=new PDO($db_cstr, $username,$password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

foreach ($parser->bookingDataResponse->bookingDataResult->Bookings as $row) 
{
   $SupplierCode = ($row->SupplierCode);
   $UnitCode = ($row->UnitCode);


   $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `bookingData` (`SupplierCode`, 'UnitCode') VALUES (?,?)");
   $stmt->execute(array($SupplierCode,$UnitCode));

}
```

Comment: Where is the code you've written to insert the data to the database?

Comment: You'll have to obtain each variable (that should go into the DB) manually. For example: `$supplier_code = $simpleXMLObject->bookingDataResponse->bookingDataResult->Bookings[$i]->SupplierCode;`. When all the variables are available, it should be fairly straight forward to write a query using those. Please note.. `$i` will be used to iterate through the object `Bookings`, which you can get the size of by: `count($simpleXMLObject->bookingDataResponse->bookingDataResult->Bookings)`

Comment: So, what you're saying is that with the INSERT function I have just added to the question is that I am not getting the data early enough?

Comment: You cannot freely mix database extensions. If you chose PDO, stick to it! Furthermore, the whole point of prepared statements is not having to escape every individual variable, but you're doing extra work to escape data twice and get it corrupted.

Comment: Good point. Will update and post new code.

Comment: I have also updated this with: `code`foreach ($parser->bookingDataResponse->bookingDataResult->Bookings as $row)`code`. Would this traverse the XML correctly @DhruvSaxena

Comment: Yes @NickGreen, I believe it should. If you do encounter any errors with this traversal though, kindly share the problem, along with the XML structure (if it's any different from what's included in the sample above), and we could try and figure out what it is. Cheers! :)